# Post image from local machine to user wall of Facebook

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

How can i post images using `slRequest` to Facebook user wall ?

```
-(IBAction)done
{
    NSString *message=@"hello";

    NSString *picture=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"4" ofType:@"jpg"];

    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:message, @"message",picture,@"picture", nil];
}
```

Comment: which facebook api you are using ?

Comment: ios6.0 social framework

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one and you know you are getting path from NSBundle not image so you  need to get first image from picture path and then do it.

```
NSString *picture=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"4" ofType:@"jpg"];
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:picture];

       NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:message, @"message",image, @"picture",nil];
```

Comment: same again ,my app is crashing

Comment: i am getting crash here                                        [fbShareRequest      performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        // In the completion handler, echo back the response
        // which should the Facebook post ID
        
        NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"returned info: %@", response);
    }];

Comment: Sorry dear i don't know what you did in your code so plz do your self.

Answer (score 0):

try this,use `@"source"` key for post **image**

```
 NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:_image, @"source",msg,@"name",nil];
//_image is UIImage
```

Comment: same problem of crashing  [UIImage length] unrecogniozed selector sent to instance